# Regex, find semicolons not within block comments ( /* */)

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to find semicolons that are not within block comments to split into an array of strings (Java).

Here is the regex I am currently using:

```
(?<!\/\*.\s\S);(?!.*\s*\S*\*\/)
```

I am attempting to use a negative lookbehind and lookahead to accomplish this, but all but last of the semicolons repeated on separate lines within the block comment are found. The last semicolon within the block comment however is not.

I am using https://regexr.com/ (with the PCRE regex engine selected) to test the above regular expression.

I am testing this with the following example code:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST;

SELECT * FROM TEST;

/* 
SELECT * FROM TEST;
SELECT * FROM TEST;
SELECT * FROM TEST;
SELECT * FROM TEST;
SELECT * FROM TEST;
*/
SELECT * FROM TEST;
```

I have also used the following regex, which appears to be getting the same result as my above regex, except with two lookaheads:

```
(?!\/\*\s*\S*)(;)(?!\s*\S*.*\*\/)
```

Also, it appears that by adding \s*\S*.* to the lookahead at the end of the regex, I can 'hack' my way around this issue, as each addition appears to fix the issue for one of the semicolons within the block comment. For example, if I have '\s*\S*.*' twice in the last lookahead, I can have up to two semicolons within the block comment commented out.

Basically, I'm all over the place on this one...

So to wrap up, I'm trying just to get the semicolons of queries outside the block comments.

As you can tell, I'm not very experienced with regex, and I've unfortunately been struggling almost all day with this. Any pointers would be much appreciated! Thanks!

**Here is a handy link that'll take you to my regex within regexr with the example code loaded: https://regexr.com/3junf**

Comment: This would be easy to do with just a loop and a test for `/*`.

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool for this job.  Remove the comments first, then look for semicolons.  But then, what about semicolons inside strings?  What you really need is an SQL parser.  Regex is the "hammer" of programming.  When someone gives you a hammer, everything looks like a nail.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

This will answer your immediate question (sort of, I didn't use regex), but Jim is right, if you're parsing SQL you need a parser.

```
public class BlockComment {

   static StringReader test = new StringReader ( "This is test1;\nThis is test2;\n" +
           "/*This is test3;\nThis is test4;*/\nThis is test5;" );

   public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {

      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new SkipBlockComments( test ) );
      String line;
      while( (line = br.readLine()) != null ) {
         System.out.println( line );
      }

   }

   public static class SkipBlockComments extends FilterReader {

      private boolean inBlock;

      public SkipBlockComments( Reader r ) {
         super( r );
         if( !markSupported() ) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }

      @Override
      public int read() throws IOException {
         for( ;; ) {
            int character = super.read();
            if( !inBlock ) {
               if( character == '/' && nextCharEquals( '*' ) ) {
                  inBlock = true;
               } else {
                  return character;
               }
            } else {
               if( character == '*' && nextCharEquals( '/' ) ) {
                  inBlock = false;
               }
            }
         }
      }

      private boolean nextCharEquals( char c ) throws IOException {
         mark( 1 );
         if( super.read() == c )
            return true;
         reset();
         return false;
      }


      @Override
      public int read( char[] buf, int start, int length ) throws IOException {
         int c = read();
         if( c == -1 ) return -1;
         buf[start] = (char) c;
         return 1;
      }

      @Override
      public int read( char[] buf ) throws IOException {
         return read( buf, 0, 1 );
      }
   }
}
```